# Angular2 code throws an Error with TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have a .net Wepapi project as Backend and a Frontend written with Angular2 all included in a visual studio solution.
The build locally works fine but if I build it with the TFS Online build in my CD Pipeline the build fails. I recive the following error:

> Build: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

and some others like this.

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "emersy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

this my typings

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

and this my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

NOTE: I use xaml build and not the new build engine.

here my systems.js.config

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        transpiler: 'ts',
        typescriptOptions: {
            tsconfig: true
        },
        meta: {
            'typescript': {
                "exports": "ts"
            }
        },
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'ts': 'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
            'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',

        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.ts',
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**EDIT1:**
After migrating the build to vnext the build now work's and don't gives a build error. Now I have added the deployment on my azure app as build step. The app wass dropped on the azure app but my angular code doesn't work. 
I get this error:

```
mysite.azurewebsites.net/:38 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/app/main.ts
    Error loading http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/app/main.ts
```

Looks like that is not coping npm modules

This is my build config
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 3:**
MSBuild Arguments

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(build.stagingDirectory)
```

[image]

Comment: Will be helpful to know how the build fails. Is there an error message maybe?

Comment: oh sorry you are right :-) Build: Cannot find module '@angular/core'. added also to the post above

Comment: How are you loading your angular app on your page? System.Import? If so, what does your systemjs.config file look like?

Comment: added system.js.config above

Comment: It's better that you can share a simple project on the OneDrive, we can make the test directly. Can you share a simple project on the OneDrive? On the other hand, based on this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool), "the hosted XAML build controller is no longer supported. Accounts created on or after April 2016 do not have access to it. We plan to remove the hosted XAML build controller from all accounts, possibly as soon as March 2017.". Can you migrate XAML build to Vnext build?

Comment: hey @starain. you can try the official angular2 quickstart from here https://github.com/angular/quickstart. i will try also to create a vnext build

Comment: i have changed it to vnext build. seems to work but my npm modules are missing and i think even the ts files

Comment: Do you have npm install task in your build definition to install the missing modules?

Comment: yes in the new vnext build yes and now the build works but not the deployed app.

Comment: What's the issue with the deployed app? Which vnext build task do you use to deploy it?

Comment: How do you want to deploy app and what steps you deploy app locally?

Comment: locally I hit f5 in visual studio :-)

Comment: @cpiock What's the detail of Visual Studio Build step? You can provide the screenshot too.

Comment: @cpiock This article about how to run npm install in azure, you can try it and check the result. (https://github.com/woloski/nodeonazure-blog/blob/master/articles/startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure.markdown)

Answer (score 0):

After migrating the build to vnext the build now work's and don't gives a build error. Now I have added the deployment on my azure app as build step. The app wass dropped on the azure app but my angular code doesn't work. 
I get this error:

```
mysite.azurewebsites.net/:38 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/app/main.ts
    Error loading http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/app/main.ts
```

Looks like that is not coping npm modules

This is my build config
[image]

Comment: You can add the new issue to your original post or create a new thread of this issue. The question or issue should not be in the answer. In addition, for this issue, you can provide the details of npm install, build solution an Copy and Publish build artifacts steps.

Comment: This article may benefit you: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/

Comment: added all to the first post. should i do also this in npm task? 
npm run typings install

Comment: Is the npm module included in the deployment package?

Comment: i have seen in the zip the modules folder isn't included

Comment: @cpiock Could you publish project to file system and copy node_module to the published folder through Copy File task, after that create a zip file with that folder through zip task?